# Is an infinite radius hypersphere always a hyperplane?

Tags: geometry

This feels like a very simple question to me, but I just can't quite rationalize it in my head, and can't find a lot of good information on the subject.

I'm attempting to generalize a problem into higher dimensions, and was going to make the claim that a hypersphere of infinite radius would be identical to a hyperplane. I had a moment of doubt and decided to look it up, and wouldn't you know it, it seems this is so.

That being said, my original logic revolved around an 'observer' on the outside of the sphere. As the radius grows, the curvature decreases, and once the sphere is infinite, it is indistinguishable from a hyperplane.

In 2D, you'd have a circle. From a 2D observer outside the circle, it would appear to be a line segment that slowly grew in size until, at infinite radius, it becomes a line. You can even make a function for this exact line; if you create a ray between the center of the circle and the observer, it is tangent to the circle at the intersection point.

However, I run into a problem when the observer is *inside* the circle (or more generally, the hypersphere). Sure, it still appears to just be a line, but I don't see how you can make an equation for the hyperplane here. Well, actually, I can; it's $x^2+y^2=r^2$ where $r=\infty$ (Does this work? Would it be better to say "where $r$ approaches $\infty$"?). But this doesn't fit the generalized equation for a 2D hyperplane; $a+bx+cy=0$ (taken from [Equation of a hyperplane in two dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2533114/equation-of-a-hyperplane-in-two-dimensions)), assuming $b$ and $c$ can't contain variables. If the hyperplane could be described as so, the observer would only see it in 180 degrees of their vision, right? Sure, at an infinite radius the circle is one-dimensional, but I just don't see how you can treat it mathematically as a line.

This also brings up questions about my initial reasoning; say the circle has two observers, 90 degrees apart. As the circle grows to infinity, both would end up with different lines. So would you need an *infinite* number of hyperplanes to describe the hypersphere? Each one is identical to its neighbors, and they differ by an angle of $0$, but across the hypersphere, wouldn't you still end up with different hyperplanes?

Comment: Your question makes no mathematical sense. That said, it is sometimes good intuition - situations where thinking about a line as a circle of infinite radius helps understand something, but there is no such thing as an infinite radius. These circles just are - they don't have observers inside or outside.

Comment: @EthanBolker I get that there's no need for the observers; that was just my was of trying to rationalize the problem. Really what I want is to be able to get a vector from some point on the hypersphere to some other point. I can do that already, of course, but it just doesn't make sense that for some finite width hypersphere, I can get a vector *from every single direction*, but not as the radius approaches infinity (at least, not with the line equation example). I'd be willing to accept that's just the way it is, I'm just struggling to make sense of it.

Comment: That's just the way it is. Vectors from one point to another on a sphere are chords that go through the ball that the sphere surrounds. Vectors from one point on a plane to another lie in the plane. In this page from wikipedia you can imagine a blue vertical line that you could think of a a circle of infinite radius in this context. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_(geometry)

Comment: There are certain settings in which we have a "point at infinity" (e.g. the Riemann sphere, projective space, etc.) where it makes informal sense to talk about circles/spheres having infinite radius as a circle/sphere through the point at infinity.  Even in such a context, however, "$x^2+y^2=r^2$ when $r=\infty$" would be a degenerate circle (a point), so it's not very interesting to discuss.

Comment: Actually, I might understand a bit better now, tell me if I'm wrong. Say you have an expanding hypersphere. Let's say you have a vector from some point on the surface to the center of the hypersphere. As the sphere expands, the 'direction' of that vector remains the same (or you could say, the unit vector of said vector remains the same). As the radius *approaches* infinity, the 'direction' is still the same, *and* a hyperplane tangent to the point on the hypersphere intersects it an infinite number of times. The radius can't actually be infinity, though.

Comment: Or would said hyperplane still only intersect it once, but be $0$ distance away from every point on the hypersphere? In other words, it would 'approach' a state of intersecting the hypersphere an infinite number of times, but never actually.

Comment: Or does it just approach a hyperplane, like the circle to a line, and I'm completely wrong? Specifically, I mean the generalized equations. I could also see it being both though.

Comment: Ok, I've used a 2D example to try and help me understand this. Obviously, we can model a circle with the parametric equation $x=r\cos(t)$, $y=r\sin(t)$. Both sin/cos will evaluate to either a positive or negative constant (or $0$). As $r$ approaches $\infty$, $x$ and $y$ approach either positive or negative infinity. Given how sin/cos line up, you should be able to generate coordinates of any combination of positive and negative infinities. I think this means you should be able to get a vector from the edge of the circle to the center to come in from any direction just like a 'normal' circle.

Comment: One can make sense of this using the notion of "pointed Hausdorff convergence", but it is likely not going to be useful for you. What is your level of math education?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Not super high, up to a fairly high level of mostly 'standard' calculus, with some random offshoots I've acquired in my own time. A lot of this is probably stuff I'd have been a lot more comfortable with a year or two ago, since I'm not taking any classes at the moment. I'm always happy to learn, however, and I'll look into it. No promises though.